# DateTime formatting Month regardless of culture?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

Can we format a `DateTime` in the following way based on the users windows culture...

`en-GB` = `1st May 2023`

`en-US` = `May 1st 2023`

without explicitly checking the `CultureInfo` and setting the format for each culture via `ToString("dd MMM yyy")` or `ToString("MMM dd yyy")` respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to detect day and month order for the current culture and then select either `MMM dd yyy` format string (for, say, US culture) or `dd MMM yyy` (for GB culture).

Please, note that some cultures (e.g. Chinese) uses *year first*

```
year month day
```

format. If you insist on year to be at the end regardless the culture (so "modified" Chinese will be `month day year`) you can use [DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthdaypattern?view=net-7.0):

```
private static string MyDateTimeFormatString() =>
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern[0] == 'M'
    ? "MMM dd yyy"   // Month before day
    : "dd MMM yyy";  // Day before month

private static string MyDateTimeFormat(DateTime value) => 
  value.ToString(MyDateTimeFormatString());
```

Usage is simple

```
DateTime date = ...

var result = MyDateTimeFormat(date);
```

And so we have

```
en-GB = 01 May 2023 (United Kingdom)
en-US = May 01 2023 (United States)
cn-CN = May 01 2023 (China)
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CSNK3B)

Comment: Thankyou for introducing me to `MonthDayPattern`

Comment: I dont insist the year be at the beginning, the main objective is not to use an int for month but instead use month name either 3 or full

Answer (score 0):

You can make those method to get the time format which you have mentioned

```
        static string GetDateTimeWithFormat(DateTime date)
        {
            string day = date.Day.ToString();
            string ordinalIndicator = GetOrdinalIndicator(date.Day);
        
            return date.ToString("MMM") + " " + day + ordinalIndicator + " " + date.Year;
        }
        
        // Method to get the ordinal indicator for a day
        static string GetOrdinalIndicator(int day)
        {
            if (day >= 11 && day <= 13)
            {
                return "th";
            }
        
            switch (day % 10)
            {
                case 1:
                    return "st";
                case 2:
                    return "nd";
                case 3:
                    return "rd";
                default:
                    return "th";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Side note: `return $"{date:MMM} {day}{ordinalIndicator} {date.Year}";` seems to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `.ToShortDateString()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring) or [the `d` standard format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) (`.ToString("d")`).

Both of these are culture-aware and look at the system settings to know what format to show.

[image: Windows Region Settings Dialog]

However, **NONE** of these options include using the abbreviated month name or ordinal day (with the `st`, `nd`, `rd`, `th`) out of the box. For that, you'll need to write your own code.